# emr-dynamodb-connector don't save if primary key is present in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

We are using Spark job with emr-dynamodb-connector to load the data from S3 files into Dyanamodb.
https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector
But if document is already present in dynamodb, my code is replacing it.

Is there a way to avoid updating existing records (based on id) if they are present in Dynamodb. If id is present in dynamodb, i simply don't want to update it, just skip that id and write rest of records. Code i am using is

```
JobConf ddbConf = new JobConf(spark.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration());
ddbConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", tableName);
ddbConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.write.percent", "50");
ddbConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat");
ddbConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat");

JavaPairRDD<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable> ddbInsertFormattedRDD = finalDatasetToBeSaved.toJavaRDD().mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Text, DynamoDBItemWritable>() {

    @Override
    public Tuple2<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable> call(Row row) throws Exception {
        Map<String, AttributeValue> ddbMap = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= schemaDdb.length - 1; i++) {
            Object value = row.get(i);
            if (value != null) {
                AttributeValue att = new AttributeValue();
                if(schemaDdb[i]._2.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("IntegerType")){
                    att.setN(value.toString());
                }else{
                    att.setS(value.toString());
                }
                ddbMap.put((String)schemaDdb[i]._1, att);
            }
        }
        DynamoDBItemWritable item = new DynamoDBItemWritable();
        item.setItem(ddbMap);
        return new Tuple2<Text, DynamoDBItemWritable>(new Text(""), item);
    }
});
ddbInsertFormattedRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(ddbConf);
```

Answer (score 0):

By saying `Is there a way to avoid updating existing records (based on id) if they are already present`, Do you want to add another document instead of replacing/updating it?

If yes, I am afraid it wont be possible with primary key, since that should be unique and distinguishes it from other. You need to make a key non-primary in order to do this.

If you want to ignore the insertion (if item exists), you can use condition-expression `attribute_not_exists(your-key)` as defined in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites)

Comment: Sorry updated the question.
What i mean was, if document with id is already present in dynamodb, i dont want to change it at all and skip it.
Just write only nonexisting ids dynamodb.

Comment: Have you tried adding this `ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(userId)'` to your record that your are inserting?

Comment: Don't know how to add this in above spark code. or how to add while using emr-dynamodb-connector